# Printing a notebook without background color to save ink

Tags: stylesheet, printing

I sometimes need to print hard copies of my notebooks, but I really like having a background color to make the notebooks easier on my eyes. Is it possible to automatically remove the background color before sending to a printer? I couldn't find it on the options inspector. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Printing uses the "Printout" screen environment. So, you can control this behavior automatically with a stylesheet. Something like:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell @ CellGroupData[
            {
            Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],Background->RGBColor[0.9, 1, 1]],
            Cell[StyleData["Notebook","Printout"],Background->None]
            },
            Open
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

ought to do it. Change the background as appropriate.

Check by toggling the `ScreenEnvironment` setting in the `Format` menu.

**Addendum**

If you want to make this change "permanent":

```
NotebookSave[
    Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell @ CellGroupData[
            {
            Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],Background->RGBColor[0.9, 1, 1]],
            Cell[StyleData["Notebook","Printout"],Background->None]
            },
            Open
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ],
    FileNameJoin[
        {$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets","Default.nb"}
    ]
]
```

and then the next time you open Mathematica you should see a blue screen. Just delete the file to return to the default behavior.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. Does this `SetOptions[]` method have a simple global implementation?

Comment: @thejacksonjive You could save the stylesheet in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}]`. If it has the name "Default.nb", it should be the default style sheet used from then on. If it doesn't have the name "Default.nb", than you would need to change the DefaultStyleDefinitions option (use the option inspector or CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions] = name) to point to it.